# Why would somebody allow USP6293874 to lapse?

Tags: lapsed-patent, us6293874

Why would somebody allow such a valuable patent as USP6293874 to lapse for non-payment of maintenance fees?

Comment: The fee payment company may have forgot to pay the fee. If the lapse in maintenance fee payment is unintentional then it could be paid late without intervening rights.

Comment: Considering the invention, I think the OP was being facetious. However to be sure there is no misunderstanding interviewing rights kick in after the 6 months grace period. This one missed a payment in 2005. From the MPEP "No patent, the term of which has been maintained as a result of the acceptance of a late payment of a maintenance fee, shall abridge or affect the right of any person or his or her successors in business who made, purchased, imported, or used after the 6-month grace period but prior to the acceptance of the late maintenance fee anything protected by the patent, . . . "

Comment: I confess I was being facetious.  I was also testing a Java application that I use to download patent documents, to which I added a feature of alerting the user if there has been a comment posted here about the downloaded patent, and for that purpose I didn't want to comment on a "serious" patent still in force.

Comment: Thanks George for the interesting note about intervening rights which I had forgotten about.  I have thankfully not had to deal with the issue of one of my clients' maintenance fees being inadvertently missed, though occasionally lapsed patents come up in FTP/FTO investigations, for which you have to explain to the client the likelihood and ramifications of a possible revival.